# curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer for Docker Container running on Cpanel

Tags: python, docker, cpanel, gunicorn

I'm running a docker container with a python app listening at host='0.0.0.0' and port as 5050.
When I curl my main site at localhost:5000, it returns the correct result. When I curl localhost:5050, it returns

curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

This is my build file

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04


RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y python3-pip

# Install Dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install  --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


COPY search_api.py .
COPY search/ search

ENV DEBUG 0


CMD [ "gunicorn", "--workers", "2", "--threads", "1", "-b", "0.0.0.0:5050", "--timeout", "400", "search_api:app"]
```

I've verified that the container is running, and these are the logs I got back

```
[2021-05-29 17:00:43 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2021-05-29 17:00:43 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5050 (1)
[2021-05-29 17:00:43 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-05-29 17:00:43 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
[2021-05-29 17:00:43 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
```

I don't have the folder registered as an application in CPanel or anything. I basically just pulled the repository after installing docker along with docker-compose. I then proceeded to build, and then run the container. This container works locally for me, but it seems as if my web server isn't listening for it?

If anyone knows anything about this please help!

Comment: How did you start the container?

Comment: I started the container by doing the build in a bash script, then using docker-compose -f <filename> up

Answer (score 0):

I figured out so far that it has to do with the ip address that docker goes to

```
[root@host etc]# sudo ip addr show docker0
 4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
link/ether 02:42:de:53:79:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::42:deff:fe53:7921/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The IP Address that docker goes to is 172.17.0.1, which isnt localhost for me. I wish it was because it would make it a whole lot easier. **I am now able to access the app when I call 172.17.0.1:5050, So thats a bandaid solution**. Im going to try to find a way to make this localhost instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a firewall issue. I disabled the firewall and it worked.

I got a clue by curling the docker IP, which properly output the html homepage.

```
sudo ip addr show docker0
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:a9:60:8e:f4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

curl 172.17.0.1:5870
```

Before disabling firewall:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:5870
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

curl 0.0.0.0:5870
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

After: I get the HTML page output.